# Spring Hibernate: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a spring-boot app and trying to build my repository, and am having an issue with Hibernate.

Pom dependencies: (there are more, just posting what i felt relevant)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Application.properties

```
# Properties for Spring datasources
#
# If multiple datasources are needed, the autoconfiguration will need
# to be excluded (add "(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)" to the
# @SpringBootApplication annotation in TankInventoryApplication).
#
# Then manual datasources will have to configured in a @Configuration annotated config class
#
spring.datasource.url=<url>
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


# Properties for Hibernate
#
# Use empty string for hbm2ddl.auto to suppress warning message
# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate - doesn't work
#
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.useSecondLevelCache=false
hibernate.cacheProviderClass=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
hibernate.cacheRegionFactoryClass=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.hbm2DdlAuto=
```

Repository:

```
//@Repository
//public interface PWeightTagsRepository extends JpaRepository<PTags, Integer>{
//
//    @Query(value = "SELECT T FROM PTags T WHERE T.adbLDeliveryStatus = 'N' ORDER BY T.adbSequence ASC")
//    List<PTags> getNewMessages();
//}

@Repository
public class PWeightTagsRepository{
    @Autowired
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<PTags> getNewMessages(Integer limit){
        javax.persistence.Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT T.* FROM GSTARTIB.P_TAGS T WHERE T.ADB_L_DELIVERY_STATUS = 'N'");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

My confusion is that, if I uncomment the first function in the repository, it will run and return results without any problem.

But, when running the second function, I get: `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101` error even though in my application.properties file I have a dialect declared.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, i found the problem. The error message it gives seems misleading to me, as it doenst match what the solution is. I needed to provide the `createNativeQuery` function with a .class to cast the results too. 
`em.createNativeQuery(<query>, PTags.class)` fixed the issue.

Comment: Please post it as an answer and accept it, so others see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.

The error message it gives seems misleading to me, as it doesn't match what the solution is.

I needed to provide the `createNativeQuery` function with a `.class` to cast the results too.

`em.createNativeQuery(<query>, PTags.class)` fixed the issue